# Java/Regex - match everything until next match

Tags: java, regex

How do I match everything till the next match with Java/Regex ? For example, I have the string:

> "Check the @weather in new york and @order me a pizza"

I want to get two matches:

1. `@weather in new york and`
2. `@order me a pizza`

I attempted following: `@.+@` but it selects the `@` symbol from next match as well.

Comment: Lookahead for the last `@` instead, or use `[^@]+`

Comment: Just a thought, but wouldn't a non-greedy operator work too? `@.+?`

Comment: Groups are just for that: `(@[^@]+?)(@.+)$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe, this simple expression might be close to what you have in mind:

```
@[^@]*
```

#### Test

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class re{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        final String regex = "@[^@]*";
        final String string = "Check the @weather in new york and @order me a pizza";

        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
            for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
                System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
            }
        }


    }
}
```

#### Output

```
Full match: @weather in new york and 
Full match: @order me a pizza
```

---

> If you wish to explore/simplify/modify the expression, it's been
>   explained on the top right panel of
>   [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/8aHMsH/1/). If you'd like, you
>   can also watch in [this
>   link](https://regex101.com/r/8aHMsH/1/debugger), how it would match
>   against some sample inputs.

---